# How do 'X-Frame-Options' and cookie "samesite" relate?

Tags: cookies, iframe

**Description:**

For cookies, with `samesite = strict` or `samesite = lax` , one cannot load web pages on an iframe. I then stumbled upon `X-Frame-Options = deny` which achieves the same effect.

**Question:**

Are the two settings necessary or is the `X-Frame-Options = deny` rendudant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Frame-Options = deny

prevents a page from being iframed into another - for phishing attacks and various other types of attacks.

The cookie change ONLY impacts cookies, so a website could still be iframed w/o additional CSP headers like x-frame-options (there are a bunch of these) -- the data wouldn't flow the same but if you only update your cookie flags, your web app/website/pages could still be spoofed/embedded by another domain, for some reason.